# Pandas: Key Error when implementing a Panel OLS

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I have the following dataframe:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/crsp.dime.mpl.df.1'

df=pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

df=df.pivot_table(index='date',columns='cid', fill_value=0,aggfunc=np.mean)

df=df.T.to_panel()

df=df.transpose(2,0,1)

df

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 505 (items) x 10 (major_axis) x 19 (minor_axis)
Items axis: N00000010 to N00035686
Major_axis axis: 2005 to 2014
Minor_axis axis: candcfscore.dyn_static to dir_ind_expendituresfor
```

I need to run a panel regression on it. To do that I am using the following code:

```
reg  = PanelOLS(y=df['billsum_support'],x=df[['years_exp', 'unemployment', 'dir_ind_expendituresfor']],time_effects=True)
reg
```

Which is giving me the following error: `KeyError: 'billsum_support'`

My understanding is that `Items axis`represents different data frames. Within each data frame I have different `endogenous`and `exogenous`variables that I intend to implement for different regression outcomes.

I have looked and am continuing to look at some of the posts regarding Panel Fixed Effects in Pandas. It seems to be deprecated; does anyone has a clue on how to implement a simple Panel OLS in Pandas/Python?

Comment: It looks like `billsum_support` is not in your items axis. I guess `df.transpose` should get the arguments in a different order.

Comment: @ptrj: Thank you for your comment! I am going to approach that problem again later; when I do, I will bear in mind your suggestion. Right now I am working on refining my pooled regression.

Comment: This problem has been [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107796/pandas-trouble-implementing-panel-ols/37108308#37108308).