# Pandas: Trouble implementing Panel OLS

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, regression

I'm having a little bit of a difficult time understanding how to implement the Panel OLS in pandas. I have received help on this topic and I thought I was understanding the situation. Now that I am trying to implement I am having difficulty. Below is my data:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/crsp.dime.mpl.df.1'



   df=pd.read_csv(url, usecols=(['date', 'cid', 'log_diff_rgdp', 'billsum_support', \
'years_exp', 'leg_totalbills', 'log_diff_rgdp', 'unemployment',  'expendituresfor',\
    'direct_expenditures', 'indirect_expenditures', 'Republican', 'sen'])))
    df.head(1)  

    cid     date    log_diff_rgdp   unemployment    leg_totalbills  years_exp   Republican  sen     billsum_support     expendituresfor     direct_expenditures     indirect_expenditures
0   N00013870   2007    0.026069    4.6     44  5   1.0     1.0     1.0     4.0     4.0     0.0


df=df.T.to_panel()

df=df.transpose(2,0,1)

df

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 505 (items) x 10 (major_axis) x 72 (minor_axis)
Items axis: N00000010 to N00035686
Major_axis axis: 2005 to 2014
Minor_axis axis: index to indirect_expenditures
```

It is my understanding (I think I could be wrong about this) that the `Items axis` contains all of the `panels`; that the `Minor_axis` contains all of the columns in each of the `panels`; and that the `Major_axis` is the `time index`. I have posted the first row of my data before sending it to `Panel`and `billsum_support` is the 4th from the last column; but, when I try to regress with `billsum_support` as the `Y` variable I get the following error.

```
reg=PanelOLS(y=df['billsum_support'],x=df[['years_exp', 'unemployment', 'dir_ind_expendituresfor']],time_effects=True)
reg
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1875             try:
-> 1876                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1877             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4027)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3891)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12408)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12359)()

KeyError: 'billsum_support'
```

I have seen the working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195432/fixed-effect-in-pandas-or-statsmodels) but this person seems to have their data in stacked format instead of Panel.
Is there someone that has some experience with OLS Panel and can understand what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it; following up on [ptrj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100928/pandas-key-error-when-implementing-a-panel-ols?noredirect=1#comment61750927_37100928), and doing some simple exploring I found the solution and will post it in the question

```
df=df.pivot_table(index='date',columns='cid', fill_value=0,aggfunc=np.mean)

df=df.T.to_panel()

df=df.transpose(2,1,0)

df=df.to_frame()
```